# Title field input textbox way too long in firefox browser

Tags: 7

This looks a very simple question but I seem to find it rather difficult to find a very easy solution...

Textboxes in forms are way too long when looking at it using Firefox but not in Chrome. In Chrome, container widths are respected so the textbox width does not go over containers' width. However, default size of 60 when using Firefox just breaks the container width declaration and does not get respected...

Comment: Use some css to define the width maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same css issue. 
you need to address the input field correctly with the inputtype "text":

e.g.

```
.mywrapper-form input[type="text"] {
   width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: i guess i was thinking of a solution that don't need css like a tweak within the admin page directly perhaps. So you wont have to go back and forth if you have a thousand forms. hopefully also this will become standard across all browsers.

Comment: i should because a pixel is a pixel in each browser, while the size="1" is an abstract unit

Comment: and why not make size equate to pixels